# How does shorthand if/else work? [PHP]

Tags: php, shorthand, shorthand-if

I've been trying to translate my PHP to the shorthand version, just for the fun of learning something new, but I can't get mine to work. I've looked at the many other questions about this on SO, but I couldn't adapt any of them to my situation.

What I want to translate to shorthand:

`if ($active_page === "front-page") {echo $active_page;}`

What I have:

`echo ($active_page === 'front-page') ? 'front-page';` **< Doesn't work**

I know it's a very short sentence already, but just for the sake of learning something new I want to make it shorthand. When giving me the solution, please try to explain what I was doing wrong and how to approach it correctly in the future.

Comment: statement ? true : false;

Comment: It's a shorthand if/else, not simply a shorthand if: `echo ($active_page === 'front-page') ? 'front-page' : '';`

Comment: I think you will want to add a second parameter so that `echo` has a parameter if your condition is not met. I.e. `echo ($active_page === 'front-page') ? 'front-page' : '';`

Comment: @Mark Baker So it doesn't work because I forgot the `else`?

Comment: @Rvervuurt precisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
condition ? then statement : else statement;
```

Note, the else statement must be present. As the comments suggest, the else could be `''`

Comment: Ah ok, so it's because I didn't add that, that it didn't work? Why can a normal if-statement work without the else, but not a shorthand if-statement? Is it because it's a shorthand if/else-statement?

Comment: Although correct your explanation is a little confusing.

Comment: In other words, it isn't just an alternative syntax for good old `if`. It's an entirely different construct.

Comment: A normal `if` statement is a lot more complex a structure, because it also supports `elseif` as well as `else`.... technically the "shorthand" version isn't actually an shorthand `if/else` statement, but an operator (the ternary operator)

Answer (score 1):

The way to define it is

```
statement ? true : false;
```

So for your example, you also need a false value.

```
echo ($active_page === 'front-page') ? 'front-page' : 'Some default value.';
```

[Here's a link](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) I found that has some good information on them.

One point from that link, incase it breaks, is you can nest the inline ifs.

```
echo ($active_page === 'front-page') ? (($somevar > 5) ? 'Above 5' : 'Below 5') : 'Some default value.';
```

Comment: I'd never recommend stacking ternary operators, because it's very hard to read the logic correctly

Comment: I agree to some extend, if it's just one like in the example, and it isn't very long, I'll stack, but anything more, I agree, separate it out.